# Conversion failed when converting the varchar to data type int when inserting multiple items

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, type-conversion, sqldatatypes

I came across the following scenario:

```
CREATE TABLE Test (Foo NVARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT INTO Test (Foo) VALUES ('1.0')
INSERT INTO Test (Foo) VALUES (1)
```

Both of the inserts work fine. But when we insert them together like this:

```
INSERT INTO Test (Foo) VALUES
('1.0'),
(1)
```

I get this error

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1.0' to data type int

I don't understand why it tries to convert the value into an `int` and I can't find any documentation about this behavior. It doesn't matter what the order of the inserts is or if it's written like `(N'1.0')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`VALUES`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) is a table value constructor, consisting of rows and columns, so [data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) rules apply to determine the data type of the column:

> The values specified in a multi-row INSERT statement follow the data
> type conversion properties of the UNION ALL syntax. This results in
> the implicit conversion of unmatched types to the type of higher
> precedence.

In your example, one value is an INT and other is VARCHAR, the winner data type is INT. When converting ALL values to INT, `'1.0'` fails (it is not an INT literal but a DECIMAL literal) hence the error.

For the above example, you need to perform explicit `CAST` on all non-varchar values i.e. `CAST(1 AS VARCHAR(1))` so that the effective data type of the column is VARCHAR.